# Could not create local repository at /var/root/.m2/repository

Tags: java, maven

My local maven repo is here `/Users/power/.m2/repository`.

But I got this error

```
[java] [ERROR] Could not create local repository at /var/root/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
```

Seems Maven thinks that it should use a root user repo. How can I fix it? I don't need to run my maven tasks using root permissions.

Comment: Do you run maven as `root`?

Comment: Nope, I do not run it as `root`. But I checked out the project as `root`.

Comment: recheck your local repo by opening Maven Repository (Window-> Show View->Maven Repository (If u r using Eclipse IDE))

Answer (score 15):

The default maven repository is

```
${user.home}/.m2/repository/
```

but you can use settings.xml ( `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` ) to change it to a folder that you have permissions on. Or conf/settings.xml in the ${MAVEN_HOME} and change:

```
<settings>
...
<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo/</localRepository>
...
</settings>
```

Ideally, you should run maven as yourself and not root to make sure you have permissions or doing 'ksu' first and then use command line.

Answer (score 5):

This error can occur if there is a file called .m2. (Most probably created mistakenly. This happened to me when I copied settings.xml as .m2) If you can delete this and run mvn command again it will create the .m2 folder and you can proceed without a hassel.

Comment: If you do this in a Dockerfile: `ADD settings.xml /root/.m2` it will do exactly this. Use: `ADD settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml` to avoid the error.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the `.m2` folder manually helps sometimes

Your `.m2` folder might be corrupted and it doesn't permit you to create new or replace existing with new `.m2` folder, so delete the existing `.m2` folder manually by entering the below commands.

To view the existing `.m2` folder

```
ls -ltra
```

To Delete it manually

```
sudo rm .m2
```