# Jenkins Issue - Could not create local repo

Tags: java, jenkins

I've been using Jenkins for the past few months and had no issues until now.

When pushing my changes, a build normally starts for that branch in Jenkins. Then once it completes successfully, my colleague merges and then a build runs for the main branch.

The issue we are having is the main branch fails to build, displaying this error:

```
09:34:04 [ERROR] Could not create local repository at /opt/jenkins/workspace/Company-Build-develop/.repository -> [Help 1]
```

We have never encountered this problem before, and the change being pushed was a very minor one (we commented out a front end graphic).

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Comment: does jenkin user have permission to create folder at path specified? does repository should be hidden?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30847251/2987755