# how to fix "Maven Could not create local repository" in Google Cloud Bigtable

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a problem with maven it error says "Could not create local repository". I try to .m2 already but it says don't have the repository name m2. I have check file it doesn't have m2 because Maven doesn't have permission to create the repository. I'm newbie in here please help me to fix it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the link in the second picture? Try changing the permissions in your .m2 permissions to be writable by Maven.

Comment: What do you want to do in cloud shell by maven?

Comment: to Mangu How can I change permission in .m2 ?

Comment: To howie I just want to follow the tutorial about bigtable query

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about what it is you're trying to do? What tutorial are you following, and what step are you getting stuck on?

Comment: @DouglasMcErlean I just do some tutorial to understand how big table work so I follow this [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-bigtable-intro-java/index.html#6) and stuck on mvn command

Comment: Did you run `cd cbt-intro-java` which has the maven package for the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely there's a file or permissions problem with the path:
`/home/jurant_subcheevaanan/.m2`. You can try removing the `.m2` directory entirely. See also the guidance and workarounds here:

[Could not create local repository at /var/root/.m2/repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847251/could-not-create-local-repository-at-var-root-m2-repository)