# Anypoint Studio could not create local repository at C:\Users\Mohammed -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, windows, maven

I am developing simple mule application using  Anypoint Studio and when I run the project as mule application give me this error:

> Could not create local repository at C:\Users\Mohammed -> [Help 1]

Comment: May be here you can find your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847251/could-not-create-local-repository-at-var-root-m2-repository

Comment: I saw,no perfect answer there, I defined my local repo in maven/conf/settings.xml but without effect!